# Inline SVG always misaligned (lower in y-position to its parent)?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an inline svg [simple icon] surrounded by an element, which no matter what I've tried, the svg will not stay in the confines of its parent [slightly above it, as in, like there is a 'margin-top: -5px'].  Honestly, I have suffered from this problem for an eternity and usually add hackish CSS to get the positioning correct via margins/padding etc., but really wish to know the true cause.
So basically, why is this - and how does one fix it?

I have also created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hfzh43fg in case the code snippet misbehaves:

***To see the crux of the issue, look at the < svg > element as opposed to its parent < li > element - as you can see - it's not contained?***

[**Please note**: I wish to have the logo perfectly centered on both axis'.]

```css
.icon,
.icon svg path {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  fill: white;
}

#facebook:hover,
#facebook:hover svg path {
  fill: #3c5a99;
}

.socialLink-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
}

.socialLink {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.socialLink li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.socialLink li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="zone zone-footer-quad-first" shape-id="77">
  <svg style="display: none;" shape-id="80">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="Facebook" id="facebook" shape-id="80">
      <path class="style8" d="M189 0H11C4.9 0 0 4.9 0 11V189c0 6.1 4.9 11 11 11h95.8v-77.5H80.8V92.4 h26.1V70.1c0-25.8 15.8-39.9 38.8-39.9c11 0 20.5 0.8 23.3 1.2v27l-16 0c-12.5 0-15 6-15 14.7v19.3h29.9l-3.9 30.2h-26V200h51 c6.1 0 11-4.9 11-11V11C200 4.9 195.1 0 189 0z"
      display="inline" id="_facebook" shape-id="80" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  <div class="socialLink-wrapper" shape-id="80">
    <ul class="socialLink" shape-id="80">
      <li class="facebook" shape-id="80">
        <svg class="icon" id="facebook" shape-id="80">
          <use xlink:href="#facebook" shape-id="80" />
        </svg>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance, PP.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `vertical-align`. What `vertical-align: middle` does is that it
>   aligns the middle of the `element` with the `baseline` plus half the
>   `x-height` of the `parent`.

So, give

```
.icon, .icon svg path{
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/Jinukurian7/hfzh43fg/6/

```css
.vcenter {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 39px;
  float: none !important;
}

.icon,
.icon svg path {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: fill 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
  fill: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#facebook:hover,
#facebook:hover svg path {
  fill: #3c5a99;
}


/*NEW*/

.socialLink-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
}

.socialLink {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
}

.socialLink li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.socialLink li a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="zone zone-footer-quad-first" shape-id="77">
  <svg style="display: none;" shape-id="80">
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 200 200" class="Facebook" id="facebook" shape-id="80">
      <path class="style8" d="M189 0H11C4.9 0 0 4.9 0 11V189c0 6.1 4.9 11 11 11h95.8v-77.5H80.8V92.4 h26.1V70.1c0-25.8 15.8-39.9 38.8-39.9c11 0 20.5 0.8 23.3 1.2v27l-16 0c-12.5 0-15 6-15 14.7v19.3h29.9l-3.9 30.2h-26V200h51 c6.1 0 11-4.9 11-11V11C200 4.9 195.1 0 189 0z"
      display="inline" id="_facebook" shape-id="80" />
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  <div class="socialLink-wrapper" shape-id="80">
    <ul class="socialLink" shape-id="80">
      <li class="facebook" shape-id="80">
        <svg class="icon" id="facebook" shape-id="80">
          <use xlink:href="#facebook" shape-id="80" />
        </svg>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are dealing with the problem visualised in this image: [image: svg out of li box]

In [this fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elrumordelaluz/02f6bfrL/3/) is showing the same behaviour with this situation solved: [image: svg inside li box]

First of all, added the `viewBox` attribute to the `svg` container to make it responsible to the size of its parent:

```
<svg class="icon" id="facebook" shape-id="80" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <use xlink:href="#facebook" shape-id="80" />
</svg>
```

Then deleted, the specific `width` and `height` applied in it and its `path`s and add `display` stuff.

```
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  ...
}
```

And control the size from the `li`

```
.socialLink li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
}
```